# how I can Print report from menu in odoo13 qweb report

Tags: odoo, qweb

the error is:
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/asad/custom/programming/environments/odoo/src/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 2049, in report_download
data = dict(url_decode(url.split('?')[1]).items())  # decoding the args represented in JSON
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

in your python code add : data={} and put this in report action parameters after self like :

```
data={}
return self.env.ref('ab_cpem.action_report_cpem_alertes').report_action(self, data=data)
```